# In order to determine spring constant of a vertical spring why don’t we use $mg=kx$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

Why don’t we apply $mg=kx$ instead of using the law of energy conservation to determine the value of spring constant?

Comment: Considering (clarify a bit) m is the mass of a body you attach to the spring, the body performs a SHM as you know. So the force by spring continuously changes but the mass is obviously constant. So you will have erroneous data.

Comment: try to think, when is spring force equal to the gravity force?

Comment: Undergrads I have taught lab do these exact experiments, they put masses on a spring and measure the elongation to its new equilibrium point for each mass. A plot of m vs $(x_0-x)$ will give a slope $\frac{k}{g}$. If you assume locally that g doesn't vary much (one can also include any uncertainties $\sigma_g$) you can use usual error propagation to determine $k\pm \sigma_k$. You just have to be sure the spring has actually come to rest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the equation $mg = kx$ to determine the value of the spring constant. This equation relates the weight of an object (mg) to the spring constant ($k$) and the elongation of the spring ($x$).

To use this equation, you need to ensure that the spring is in equilibrium, meaning there are no net external forces acting on it, and is at rest. In this situation, the weight of the object hanging from the spring ($mg$) is balanced by the restorative force exerted by the spring ($kx$). The elongation of the spring at equilibrium, denoted by $x$, is also the maximum elongation caused by the mass m without any external force.

By measuring the mass m and the elongation x, you can solve the equation for the spring constant k. Rearranging the equation, we have:

$$k = (mg) / x$$

So, dividing the weight of the object ($mg$) by the elongation of the spring ($x$) will give you the value of the spring constant. Keep in mind that this equation assumes that the spring follows Hooke's Law, which states that the restoring force exerted by a spring is directly proportional to its elongation.

Answer (score 0):

Is working of course, question is precision and the fact that its difficult to get the mass to abolute rest.

Lengths can at best be determined up to a wavelength ~ 10^-6 m with laser equipment. This is the precision for time  for a good quarz watch precision of 1 s/month. Reading times of n periods  involves a constant uncertainty of lenght and 1/n of the one periods time uncertainty.

But the greatest obstacle is, that g is measured by the same equipment and it varies wildly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The local gravitational acceleration might be different point to point but I wouldn't classify it as "varying wildly" that is a strange claim to make.